# (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Access.get/3

Tags: elixir

I am new to Elixir and currently making a transaction from Ruby. I am struggling to get around an error I am getting and because Elixir does not have `object.class`, I am struggling to understand what data type am I returning back and how to troubleshoot it.

Anyway I am trying to seed a database from a CSV but getting the error

Below is my code

```
File.stream!('users_departs.csv')
|> Stream.drop(1)
|> CSV.decode(headers: [:name, :title, :departments])
|> Enum.take(10
|> Enum.each( fn(x) -> IO.inspect(x[:ok]) end )

 Error

** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Access.get/3

The following arguments were given to Access.get/3:

    # 1
    {:ok,
     %{
       departments: "Sales|Marketing",
       name: "John Smith",
       title: "Customer Service"
     }}

    # 2
    :ok

    # 3
    nil
(elixir) lib/access.ex:306: Access.get/3
(stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
(stdlib) erl_eval.erl:878: :erl_eval.expr_list/6
```

I have 2 models, User, and Departments and I would like to seed the departments first, then create a user and then associate a user-department mapping but am struggling to get past this step.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Access.get/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html#get/3) is a elixir function, that, according to the documentation:

> Gets the value for the given key in a container (a map, keyword list, or struct that implements the `Access` behaviour)

Check the error msg,

```
{:ok,
   %{
     departments: "Sales|Marketing",
     name: "John Smith",
     title: "Customer Service"}}
```

is not “map, keyword list or struct etc.” It is a *tuple*, consisting of `:ok` atom and the map.

That seems, `CSV.decode(headers: [:name, :title, :departments])` returns `{:ok, value_decode}`.

So you can not pipe it to [`Enum.take/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#take/2) as is.

Just

```
{:ok, decode_csv} =
  File.stream!('users_departs.csv')
  |> Stream.drop(1)
  |> CSV.decode(headers: [:name, :title, :departments])

decode_csv
|> Enum.take(10)
|> Enum.each( fn(x) -> IO.inspect(x[:ok]) end )
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was helpful. I still got the error ```** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: #Stream<[enum:```. I did the following ```stream = File.stream!('users_departs.csv') |> Stream.drop(1) |> CSV.decode(headers: [:name, :title, :departments]) mapped_stream = Stream.map(stream, fn(x) -> { :ok, map } = x ; map end ) Enum.each(mapped_stream, fn(x) -> IO.inspect(x) )``` And that worked!! Thanks again.