# (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Access.get/3 - separate question because additional ones in the topic are being deleted

Tags: elixir

Problem no. 1 why my additional question in [(FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Access.get/3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50671952/functionclauseerror-no-function-clause-matching-in-access-get-3) was deleted by moderator whereas it was asking a question about the answer to the original quesiton

Problem no. 2 I am trying to comprehend why:
the original and (NOT working) answer

```
{:ok, decode_csv} =
  File.stream!('users_departs.csv')
  |> Stream.drop(1)
  |> CSV.decode(headers: [:name, :title, :departments])
```

raises:

```
== Compilation error in file lib/data_dictionary.ex ==
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: #Function<62.51129937/2 in Stream.transform/3>
...
```

The documentation is extremely vague on this and I am unlucky enough to have just upgraded to the 2.2.1 version of the CSV.

I am quite puzzled not knowing how the heck process the return value of the CSV.decode...

With my best wishes Tomasz

Comment: Answering your first question: Stack Overflow has it’s rules. Questions should be asked as questions and should not be put as answers.

Comment: Moreover, meta-commentary ("why my additional question...") should be on meta.stackoverflow.com. Keep questions questions.

Answer (score 2):

As clearly stated in the documentation, [`CSV.decode/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/csv/CSV.html#decode/2) returns *a stream*. Until you have it terminated, it’s a stream. That said, what you need is to ensure you a) terminate it somehow, e.g. by converting to the list with [`Enum.to_list/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Enum.html#to_list/1), and b) you properly handle the return values, which are basically tuples `{:ok, values}` *or* `{:error, description}`.

For the trivial case, when you are fine with raising on errors, just use the banged version [`CSV.decode!/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/csv/CSV.html#decode!/2) which returns *a streamed list* or raises if it fails to parse any row.

```rb
'users_departs.csv'
|> File.stream!()
|> Stream.drop(1)
|> CSV.decode!(headers: [:name, :title, :departments])
|> Enum.to_list() # ESSENTIAL!
```